# wicket response trimmed at the end

Tags: wicket, response

I have a trouble with output data in response.

```
@Override
protected ResourceResponse newResourceResponse(Attributes attributes) {
    ResourceResponse response = new ResourceResponse();
    response.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.INLINE);
    response.disableCaching();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    stringBuilder.append(";").append(charset == null ? DEFAULT_CHARSET : charset);
    response.setContentType(stringBuilder.toString());
    response.setLastModified(Time.now());

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        fillOutputStream(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error when try to fill data for html report", e);
    }
    String message = null;
    try {
        message = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        logger.warn("Unknown encoding");
        message = outputStream.toString();
    }
    final CharSequence data = message;

    response.setContentLength(data.length());
    response.setWriteCallback(new WriteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void writeData(Attributes attributes) {
            attributes.getResponse().write(data);
        }
    });

    configureResponse(response, attributes);
    return response;
}
```

Here data is html page which has been generated in fillOutputStream() method and transform to CharSequence.

I've logged the data and it have correct content which I expect but in the result I have trimmed at the end page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of String is not necessarily equal to its byte count.

Use a CountingOutputStream instead (e.g. from guava).